# Activation of facebook Instant article

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I need to activate Facebook instant article(recently launched) on my WordPress website. i just use this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/allfacebook-instant-articles/ but it will not works. it will not have any sufficient documentation to implement it on my website. Please advice to activate this plugin  Or please suggest any other method to activate this facility.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used that plugin before but there is another one called Facebook Instant Articles for WP: https://wordpress.org/plugins/fb-instant-articles/ It is the official one from Automattic (the parent company of WordPress).

It works great, just install and activate it.  It will put a feed for instant articles at /feed/instant-articles

It doesn't have much for documentation and doesn't include a WP Admin interface but works well and has lots of hooks that you can use to extend or modify your feed.  At [AdPlugg](http://www.adplugg.com), we successfully extended it to allow you to drag and drop ads into your feed. You can read more about that here if you are interested: [Facebook Instant Article Ads](http://www.adplugg.com/blog/facebook-instant-article-ads).

Also to note is that the Facebook Instant Articles for WP plugin seems to need PHP 5.5 or higher.

Comment: succesfully installed it.  get the url /feed/instant-articles. but for submitting the rss feed in facebook page's setting page. I dont see the instant article link in the left side menu

Comment: I successfully installed it as well and got the feed (http://www.marcozanetti.it/blog/feed/instant-articles) but it doesn't seem to contain 50 posts, even though my blog has much more than 50 posts in it and facebook instant articles configuration needs at least 50. Do you happen to imagine how I could fix it?